# No menu on terminal window, open new tab?

Tags: pixel, jessie-lite, lxterminal

On my fresh install of Jessie lite on a Pi 3 my terminal window has no menu, and the classical way to open a new tab `CTRL` + `SHFT` + `t` has no effect. But on my pi zero W, with what seemed to me the same installation steps, it has a menu and opening a new tab works with the shortcut indicated. Obviously I've installed something on the Pi Zero which I didn't on the Pi 3 (2 weeks separated each installations). Both Pi 3 and 0 have PIXELS.

I can't find what I am missing to be able to open a new tab in my terminal, and (but less important to me) have a menu bar, does anybody know?

Comment: Did you perhaps install jessie (with GUI) on one and jessie lite on the other? Jessie Lite does not include the gui by default.

Comment: Steve, no, I'm positive and 100% certain that both installs are Jessie Lite based.